# EC2 AMI 2.4/2.5 dsc20/dsc21 dependency issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax

I'm trying to create a 1 node Datastax community edition cluster using this [guidelines](https://aws.amazon.com/amis/datastax-auto-clustering-ami-2-2/) on EC2 m3.xlarge (eu-west).
Here is the provided parameters:

```
  --clustername cassandra
  --totalnodes 1
  --version community
```

As mentioned in the guideline, I opened those ports:

```
  22
  8888
  1024-65355
```

Here is the error I found in ~/datastax_ami/ami.log:

```
         The following packages have unmet dependencies:
         dsc20 : Depends: cassandra (= 2.0.14) but 2.1.4 is to be installed
         [ERROR] 04/21/15-12:58:29 sudo service cassandra stop:
         cassandra: unrecognized service
         [EXEC] 04/21/15-12:58:29 sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra
         [EXEC] 04/21/15-12:58:29 sudo rm -rf /var/log/cassandra
         [EXEC] 04/21/15-12:58:29 sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/cassandra
         [EXEC] 04/21/15-12:58:29 sudo mkdir -p /var/log/cassandra
         [ERROR] 04/21/15-12:58:29 sudo chown -R cassandra:cassandra        /var/lib/cassandra:
         chown: invalid user: `cassandra:cassandra'

         [ERROR] 04/21/15-12:58:29 sudo chown -R cassandra:cassandra /var/log/cassandra:
         chown: invalid user: `cassandra:cassandra'

         [INFO] Reflector loop...
         [INFO] 04/21/15-12:58:29 Reflector: Received 1 of 1 responses from:               [u'172.31.46.236']
         [INFO] Seed list: set([u'172.31.46.236'])
         [INFO] OpsCenter: 172.31.46.236
         [INFO] Options: {'username': None, 'cfsreplication': None, 'heapsize': None, 'reflector': None, 'clustername': 'cassandra', 'analyticsnodes': 0, 'seed_indexes': [0, 1, 1], 'realtimenodes': 1, 'java7': None, 'opscenter': 'no', 'totalnodes': 1, 'searchnodes': 0, 'release': None, 'opscenterinterface': None, 'version': 'community', 'dev': None, 'customreservation': None, 'password': None, 'email': None, 'raidonly': None, 'javaversion': None}
         [ERROR] Exception seen in ds1_launcher.py:
         Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds1_launcher.py", line 33, in initial_configurations
         ds2_configure.run()
         File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds2_configure.py", line 1058, in run
         File "/home/ubuntu/datastax_ami/ds2_configure.py", line 521, in construct_yaml
         IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml'
```

Related GitHub issue: [Add support for DSC 2.2 Versions #81](https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI/issues/81)

Does anyone what I've done wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug with the dependencies - as you encountered - [Add support for DSC 2.2 Versions #81](https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI/issues/81) and was fixed in AMI 2.5.

Therefore be sure to use the new AMI. **Do not use:**

```
DataStax Auto-Clustering AMI
```

which is the AMI 2.4 version, instead use:

```
DataStax Auto-Clustering AMI 2.5.1-pv
```

or

```
DataStax Auto-Clustering AMI 2.5.1-hvm
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [github issue:](https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI/issues/81)

> Proposed fix committed to dev-2.5 and dev-2.6. Will test today and release today.